# Is there a way to view in Linux why my machine gets frozen when a specific process or a lot of processes happen?

Tags: linux, cpu, gnome

My laptop gets stuck every time it performs a lot of processes. For example, I have Google Drive third party app named "ODrive" that synchronizes Google Drive with a local folder that I have, and every time that I make a change, like moving a file from one sub-folder to another, after 1 or 2 minutes, my desktop becomes frozen and I don't know what to do. The same happens when I'm running a lot of processes on my computer or if I receive multiple notifications from an app called "GSConnect", which synchronizes my phone with the computer. The only thing that I can think of doing is manually restarting my computer.

My machine has 11.6 GBs of available RAM and an Intel Core i5 processor. I think the problem lies in my processor. Also, I need to take my computer to be checked for revising if there any problem with the hardware and applying thermal paste.

Here are the specifications of the processor:

[image]

Comment: Thank for the comments below, I manage to spot the problem: My computer is running out of RAM memory and I also noticing that my computer is not using VM paging. Ups.

Comment: The processes list shown here will help you determine what is using up all your memory.

Comment: Running "top" can show the processes using resources and using "vmstat" can show what resource is bottlenecked.

Answer (score 0):

The starting point in Linux is the "ps aux" command (no quotes).

This is roughly equivalent to Task Manager in Windows.

Please see this article to help you with an explanation.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-running-process-in-linux-using-command-line/

There are several variations of the above command to suit your needs.

See if the manufacturer has a hardware test app for linux (or bootable USB) that you can use to check for hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of an I/O error during swap, just VM paging, or from kernel space.  You can view the log of such errors via the `dmesg` command. The end of the output is the most recent events. Look for lines in the output that report an error.